# Como enviar um post usando o Django Rest Framework e Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

Como faço para enviar um post no Angular? Fiz um teste aqui e exige que informe a PK:

```
index.controller('EditController', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.save = function() {
    var in_data = { name: $scope.Job.name, description: $scope.Job.description };
    $http.put('job/5/', in_data)
        .success(function(out_data) {
            console.log("Success!");
        }).
         error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(status, data);
        });
};
});
```

O problema seria especificamente aqui:

```
$http.put('job/5/', in_data)
```

Obviamente a id não poderia ir na url. Como envio esse post sem essa id?

Quando envio sem a id este é o erro:

```
405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED
{"detail": "Method 'PUT' not allowed."}
```

Minha urls.py:

```
url(r'^job/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.job_detail, name="add_job"),
```

Minha views.py:

```
try:
    job = Job.objects.get(pk=pk)
except Job.DoesNotExist:
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

elif request.method == 'PUT':
    serializer = JobSerializer(job, data=request.DATA)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**Editado:**

Consegui alterando o método "PUT" para "POST" na `views.py` e usando `$http.post()` ao efetuar a requisição.

Comment: Se você achou a solução, crie uma resposta, não coloque dentro da pergunta como você fez. Bem-vindo.

Comment: Desculpe pelo erro, vou seguir a recomendação na próxima. Abraço!

Answer (score 1):

Apesar de ter encontra a resposta, achei por bem esclarecer algo que poderá ser útil:

De acordo com a [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) verbo `PUT` é um método idempotente, ou seja, não importa quantas vezes eu repito o pedido, a resposta do servidor é sempre a mesma. Geralmente isto significa a actualização (total) de um determinado recurso. No seu caso, estava a utilizar o PUT de forma errada, já que está a criar um novo recurso. O verbo mais apropriado, como descobriu, é o POST.

Tanto o Django como o Angular seguem a spec, daí o erro.

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento!
Abraço!